# QGIS modify rectangular shaped polygons

Tags: qgis, cad, rectangle

Within QGIS is there a simple way to modify the shape of a rectangular polygon by simply parallel translating one of the edges `(a -> a')` like shown below.

[image]

I've been looking at the CADDigitize plugin where I might achieve this by creating a parallel translated CADLine and then snapping each vertex of edge `a` to the CADLine. But for me this is quite painful and time consuming, if one has to do so very often. And furthermore, since not beeing able to exactly define the distance `aa'` it's a bit bumpy not to be able to a) drag `a'` somewhere or b) defining a point lying on `a'`.

So is there a more simple and intuitive way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried a combination of the advanced digitizing tools and reshape features.  This will allow to redraw the rectangle.  Optional tidy up would be to remove unnecessary nodes on the polygon.

[image: extending box with advanced digitizing and reshape tools]

Alternatively using the 'Node tool' and dragging the line between two nodes would also work, however there is no control on maintaining angles.

Comment: not as simple and intuitive as selecting the edge and dragging it, but much faster than my above approach! ;-) +1